# Lenovo T410 problem with "WPA & WPA 2 Enterprise" in 13.10

Tags: wireless, networking

This is a fresh install of Ubuntu 13.10 on a completely wiped clean hard disk. Dual booted with windows 7 (Boths OSs freshly installed). The install is on Ext 4 partition. And my university uses WPA2 Enterprise I believe - PEAP with MSCHAPv2.

Win 7 connects flawlessly and works fine. Ubuntu works flawlessly with the open Guest netowrk of university but not the secured one. It connects fine, and will work for 10-20 seconds but then INTERNET is lost. No ping to www.google.com. However, the network still remains connected. If I disconnect and reconnect to the wifi netowrk again, the internet will work for another 10-15 seconds before being lost. The wifi adapter I believe is "Intel Centrino Ultimate-N 6300". Here is the

```
 *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Ultimate-N 6300
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 35
       serial: 00:24:d7:38:97:c4
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.11.0-12-generic firmware=9.221.4.1 build 25532 ip=10.101.160.224 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE
802.11abgn
       resources: irq:44 memory:f2000000-f2001fff
```

Comment: Please see 11n_disable=1 here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/38826/centrino-wireless-n-1000-poor-performance-on-n-network

Answer (score 3):

Try to delete the faulty connection from list in Network Connections.

```
nm-connection-editor
```

Check if you have got wpa_supplicant installed:

```
sudo apt-get install wpasupplicant
```

After that add the connection manually. You have to create a configuration file:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

(If you don't have `gksudo`, use `sudo -H`.)

In which - editing where needed - paste this:

```
network={
        ssid="xxxxxxx"
        scan_ssid=1
        key_mgmt=IEEE8021X
        eap=PEAP
        phase2="auth=MSCHAPV2"
        identity="xxxxxxxxx"
        password="xxxxxxxxx"
}
```

Be careful as everything there may be case sensitive. After that:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces
```

It should look similar to that:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Add following lines to the file (without touching the existing ones):

```
wpa-driver wext
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

And finally restart networking

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

For me - it worked like a charm - its worth trying, but I'm not 100% sure that it'll fix your case.

In case it does not - a possible solution may be installing drivers, for instance from http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi

EDIT:

3rd possible solution - add a driver parameter:

```
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi
sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
```

You should probably try the '3rd' solution first ;)

Comment: The last step gies the following error "ERROR: Calling a sysvinit script on a system using upstart isn't supported. Please use the 'service' command instead."

Comment: Runing "sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi" says "FATAL: Module iwlwifi is in use."

Comment: Please try: 
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down, || sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi
and if there are no errors:
sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=1, || sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
(i used || just to separate the commands, paste them one by one)

Comment: The problem is most probably caused by 11n connection not working properly on your device - you have to disable it. Did the last commands work?

Comment: I'm home now where everything works fine. Will try it out again when I'm at the university tomorrow. I highly doubt this solution will work, because it seems to suggest that wireless n is a problem. However my home router is "N only" and things work flawlessly.

Comment: Wireless N works perfectly well with some but not all routers. With others, it doesn't work at all.

Comment: Probably the best solution would be writing a script enabling or disabling 11n for certain networks. You'd be able to keep using it normally for instance at home, but you'll be able to have stable network connection with 11g at your uni.

Comment: I did some searching and looked around. And although none of the commands mentioned helped fixed the problem outright, the following did `sudo modprobe -r iwldvm`, followed by `sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=1`(the latter I'm not sure if it went through). The wifi seems to be working both for the university and the N only home network as of now.

Comment: I was incorrect and this has not solved the problem. Any suggestions?